# WiFi not connecting - possibly due to a Connection-specific DNS Suffix

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, dns, wireless-adapter

I'm trying to connect to my work's wifi network, however my new accommodation seems to have set a "Connection-specific DNS Suffix", which I believe is stopping connections to other networks. Connection via ethernet is fine.

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a Dell Latitude E5550. Here's my `ipconfig /all`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Tim_Laptop
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual 
Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-57-18-78-C0-36
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : customer.blandford.derwent.lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-57-18-78-C0-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 34-E6-D7-46-A1-EE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

It appears as though `customer.blandford.derwent.lan` is to do with my accomodation's network (ran by Ask4). I've tried running `ipconfig /flushdns` (both normally and as admin) however it still doesn't work. I've had a look around other forums, etc., but couldn't find anything that seemed to work. Has anyone got any ideas of what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm not that familiar with troubleshooting network problems, so please bear with me & make any instructions clear.

Comment: "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" only affects DNS queries that don't specify the domain name, so shouldn't be a problem here. Try to set your DNS servers to [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

Comment: That seems to do the trick @harrymc, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Very good. I added an answer which you might accept (tick the V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Connection-specific DNS Suffix" only affects DNS queries that don't specify the domain name, so shouldn't be a problem here.

This might be a glitch with the DNS server you are using.
Try to set your DNS servers to [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).